# Core Data Many-to-Many Relationship NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate

I have a data model with a many-to-many relationship like `EntityA <-->> EntityB <<--> EntityC`. I used to query `EntityA` with different search criteria and I use `NSCompoundPredicate` with an array of `NSPredicate`s. On one of the predicate I wanted to query `EntityA` using `EntityC`. I tried to use the following `SUBQUERY` but it did not work.

```
searchPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(0 != SUBQUERY(EntityB, $B, (0 != SUBQUERY($B.EntityC, $EntityC, $EntityC.name like %@).@count)).@count)", name]
```

And I got the following exception,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.'
```

Is there anything I'm missing. I would appreciate any help.

Sarah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I had a lot of trouble puzzling out your predicate so take this with a grain of salt.)

I think your making this overly complicated. You should simplify with keypaths. Each EntityB has a to-one relationship to a EntityC so to search on EntityB objects all you need to do is check `EntityB.entityCRelationshipName.entityCAttribute`. So something like:

```
ALL B.EntityC.name like %@
```

In any case, (if I'm reading the predicate correctly) this:

```
SUBQUERY($B.EntityC, $EntityC, $EntityC.name like %@)
```

can only return a single object instead of a collection. Therefore, the predicate will not be able to perform a count on it. That is what your error message means.

I suggest using the predicate editor in the Data Model editor to hash out the predicates before you store them.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have used you approach before but got the following exception  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate ALL B.EntityC.name LIKE "name"' and I used the predicate editor for constructing it.

Comment: Try `ANY entityB.entityC.name LIKE[c] $aName` and provide the "aName" variable. Make sure that your relationship names aren't literally the same as the entity names.

Comment: ANY entityB.entityC.name LIKE[c] $aName worked very good, thanks