# Predicate to compare object with each other object in the same collection

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` of calendar periods which consists of `NSManagedObjects` and is modeled as shown in this screen shot:

[image: CoreDataModel]

with the following sample contents:

```
endMonth = 9;
endYear = 2012;
length = 3;
...
```

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to construct a predicate which returns only those calendar periods for which the equivalent period a year earlier exists. Example: Return the period `2012, 9, 3` (year, month, length) as result only if there is the period `2011, 9, 3` in the array. The predicate needs to compare every calendar period with each calendar period in the array.

This is the predicate which I tried:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"SUBQUERY(SELF, $x, $x.endYear == endYear - 1 "
        "AND $x.endMonth == endMonth AND $x.length = length).@count > 0"];
```

**The problem:**

However, running my app with this predicate results in a runtime crash with the error message:  **NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.'**

What is wrong with my predicate and how would I need to specify it correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822625/core-data-many-to-many-relationship-nspredicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to address the error you're seeing.  This is your predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF, $x, $x.endYear == endYear - 1 "
    "AND $x.endMonth == endMonth AND $x.length = length).@count > 0"]
```

The first argument to a `SUBQUERY` expression is a collection which the `SUBQUERY` will iterate.  Thus, you're expecting `SELF` to evaluate to either an `NSArray` or an `NSSet`.  However, your use of the keypaths `endYear`, `endMonth`, and `length` in the subquery predicate seem to indicate that you're expecting `SELF` to evaluate to a `CalendarPeriod`.  Thus, either `SELF` is a collection (and `endYear`, `endMonth`, and `length` are invalid keypaths for the collection), or `SELF` is a `CalendarPeriod` (and therefore can't be used as the `SUBQUERY`'s collection.  Based on your error, it seems to be the latter.

If we were to write your problem out (without using an `NSPredicate`), we'd probably end up with something like this:

```
NSArray *calendarPeriods = ...;
for (CalendarPeriod *period in calendarPeriods) {
  for (CalendarPeriod *otherPeriod in calendarPeriods) {
    if ([otherPeriod endYear] == [period endYear] - 1 && [otherPeriod endMonth] == [period endMonth] && [otherPeriod length] == [period length]) {
      return YES;
    }
  }
}
return NO;
```

So, how to replicate this...

Your initial attempt seems to be pretty good.  I think the only change that needs to be made is that instead of `SELF` as the first parameter to the `SUBQUERY`, you should use `%@`, and the substitute in the `calendarPeriods` collection there.  Alternatively, if you're executing this as the predicate to an `NSFetchRequest`, you could try using a `FETCH()` expression to fetch every `CalendarPeriod` object.

You're looking at pretty bad performance if you go this route, by the way.  It's a guaranteed O(N<sup>2</sup>), and you could do much better.  For example, if you fetched every `CalendarPeriod` into memory, and then inserted them into an `NSDictionary` keyed by a combination of the `endYear`, `endMonth`, and `length`, then you could cut it down to O(N) time.

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive answer, Dave. I have two follow-up questions: 1: When I replace `SELF`by `%@`in the `SUBQUERY` what would I need to specify as the parameter for the fetch request (as `CalendarPeriod` is a `NSManagedObject` which I fetch via  `NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"CalendarPeriod"]`). 2: Where do I find more information on the `FETCH()`expression you have suggested. This expression is very new to me.